# How does .configure() and .pack() work together in Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Currently trying to work with GUI's and i am having the problem, that as soon as i format a label with .pack() i can't use .configure() on the same label to change its text.

```
def browseFiles():
    global filename
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/Desktop",
                                          title = "Explorer",
                                          filetypes = (("Pics",
                                                         "*.jpg*"),
                                                       ("Text",
                                                        "*.txt*"),
                                                       ("All",
                                                        "*.*")))
      
    f = open("yeet.txt", "a")
    f.write(filename)
    f.close()
    label_file_explorer.configure(text="You chose: "+filename)
```

The label itself looks like this:

```
label_file_explorer = Label(window,text = "Label",width = 100, height = 4,fg = "blue").pack()
```

As soon as i leave the .pack() out i can't see the label, but i don't get an error, so i'd assume it works.

FYI - this is the error message: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'configure'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the `.pack()` method returns the `None` you are seeing.

I think what you meant was this:

```py
label_file_explorer = Label(window,text = "Label",width = 100, height = 4,fg = "blue")
label_file_explorer.pack()
```